# Why are the images in my inner Rows not getting displayed at the center in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a parent Row and inner Rows, each inner Row contains an Image, so I want them to get displayed at the center side by side. Currently I have even given horizontalArrangement as Center but still it's not getting displayed the way I want. only one Image is getting displayed which is displayed at the left side. Following is my code

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.absolutePadding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentWidth
import androidx.compose.material3.Divider
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.R
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.common.CommonUi
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.constants.Destinations
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue

@Composable
fun SpeechScreen1(navController: NavController) {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val swipeThreshold = 200 // Adjust this threshold as needed

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(top = 20.dp, end = 24.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
    ) {
        CommonUi().txt18San(stringResource(id = R.string.cancel),400)
    }
    Divider(color = Color(0xFFD6D6D6), thickness = 1.dp)
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 69.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 24.dp, top = 13.dp, end = 24.dp)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures { _, offset, _, _ ->
                        offsetX += offset.x
                        if (offsetX.absoluteValue >= swipeThreshold) {
                            if (offsetX > 0) {

                                navController.navigate(Destinations.SpeechScreen2)
                            }
                            offsetX = 0f
                        }
                    }
                }
        ) {
            CommonUi().txt20SansSwipeableScreens(stringResource(id = R.string.txt_please_request),400)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(9.dp))
            CommonUi().txt32SerifDisplaySwipeableScreens(stringResource(id = R.string.txt_please_request_reading_paragrap1), weight =300,
                )
        }
    }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 6.dp, top = 600.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .absolutePadding(bottom = 100.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.blackcircle), contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.width(11.dp).height(11.dp))
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.greycircle), contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.width(11.dp).height(11.dp))
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {

            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.greycircle), contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.width(11.dp).height(11.dp))
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .padding(top = 26.dp)
        ) {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.greycircle), contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.width(11.dp).height(11.dp))
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you use those "inner" rows in the first place? `Row` renders its children side by side horizontally, there is no point in using `Row` when it only has one child, which means all your inner rows are useless. Then, all your inner rows have modifier `fillMaxWidth()`, which means the first one takes the whole width and there's nothing left for the rest, that's why only the first image is displayed.

Comment: This took me a while too, but `fillMaxWidth` *always* takes all of the remaining width, regardless of any siblings that might need space too. You should probably use `weight(1f)` instead.